# handling all URLs in index.html just with JS

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I have a simple index.html in root of my example.com
Is it possible to identify all urls like exmaple.com/xyz, example.com/abc?
Just with js and redirect to new target based on "xyz", "abc", ...?

It seems I just can handle example.com/#/xyz. (I dont want that sharp)

Comment: on the browser? no, you can't. on the backend (e.g. with node)? yes, sure!

Comment: maybe with the History API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Note that making such a change also requires server side configuration to account for the virtual paths

Answer (score 0):

As @charlietfl said, it's not possible, finally I wrote a small php with this rewrite engine rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

my php, js code:

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var address = window.location.href;
//xyz in example.com/xyz
var result= address.substring(lastSlashIndex  + 1);

// go to target based on result
setTimeout(function() {
            window.location="http://example.org" + result;
        }, 500);
</script>

</html>
```